# Gradle: Equivalent to complieOnly in gradle versions > 7.0

Tags: java, spring, gradle

Is there any equivalent to compileOnly in gradle dependency methods for versions greater than 7.0?

Comment: What makes you think `compileOnly` has been deprecated and/or removed? Perhaps you're actually thinking of `compile`? Because that latter configuration has been removed and was replaced by `implementation`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply..  I went with replacing the whole dependency with some other. But I was getting error stating something like compileOnly is not valid/recognisable. So I thought it got removed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, it is still `compileOnly`: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations

Comment: Maybe OP is actually talking about `compile`, `runtime`, `testCompile`, and `testRuntime`? Because those were deprecated (a while ago, mind) and appear to have been removed in the newer releases.

Comment: @Slaw maybe; in any case the attached doc shows all the configurations available with the Java plugin.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. I went with replacing the whole dependency with some other. But I was getting error stating something like compileOnly is not valid/recognisable.

Comment: Anyone landing here might want to read this conversation to understand how to use `compileOnly`: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/is-it-recommended-to-use-compileonly-over-implementation-if-another-module-use-implementation-already/26699/2